# Software for easily editing .mod music files or rather, a sequence oriented editor

Tags: audio, music, editor, music-production

The `.mod` file format was launched on Amiga as part as the main format of [Protracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProTracker). Instead of complete recorded music, the format contains recorded samples and intructions about the order for playing/replaying them and at which volume. Think as a partial rasterized svg in the case of images.

What I want to do is to modify decades old `mod.` files created on an Amiga but not using the old way : I‘m meaning that instead of modifying hex values matching the volume at a point one by one and frequently rewrite the old file, I want to be able to delete entire samples from the file using a few clicks or copy and insert sequences in the file.

Which software would allow this ? The problem is most software supporting the `mod.` format attempt to recreate the interface of [Protracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProTracker) instead of giving the more advandced features found in other modern sampling sound software.
I would prefer a Windows or Linux solution.